# Can't delete an action using Graph API Explorer

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have an app that is successfully publishing user actions such as read.news to facebook. I'm building in a way to delete those actions if they wish. When attempting to run this code I get the following error message in my console and the Graph API Explorer:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported delete request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

I know that when I tried this over a week ago I was able to delete an action so something has changed. What is the cause of this error?

Comment: What are you doing that results in the error? I assume it's a HTTP DELETE request to `https://graph.facebook.com/{action-instance-id}` using the user's access token for your app?

Comment: Yes that's what I was doing. I've tried my token and the app token through the Graph API Explorer. Both give the same error.

Comment: And you're using the same app that posted the story?

Comment: Yep, same app. This one is boggling me. My best guess would be something in the App settings but haven't been able to find anything.